# Change PHP to a Link to a Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to replace this `get_option('mycruisine_menu_page_url')` with a link to an actual page. Can anyone tell me what I need to change to do this? Thanks so much in advance. Apologies if I somehow didn't get the code to display properly. Edit: When I say actual page, I mean a link I can put in like http://www.mydomian.com/nursery.html.

```
 <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_option('mycuisine_menu_page_url') ); ?>"     class="browse-menu"><span><?php esc_html_e('Click Here To Find Out More!','MyCuisine'); ?></span></a>
        <div id="bottom-shadow"></div>
    </div>  <!-- end .container -->
```

Comment: You mean make that into `http://mypage.com` instead?

Comment: Yes. I just added that above- realized I didn't explain enough. Sorry. I need to by able to put in a link to a page on the site that isn't the menu thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

```
<?php $my_link = "http://google.com/"; ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $my_link ); ?>" class="browse-menu"><span><?php esc_html_e('Click Here To Find Out More!','MyCuisine'); ?></span></a>
//or
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( "http://google.com/" ); ?>" class="browse-menu"><span><?php esc_html_e('Click Here To Find Out More!','MyCuisine'); ?></span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I fight for an hour and Stack Over Flow is magic in 2 minutes. Thank you!